# I have a water-saving toilet with a plastic dish inside the bowl that needs to be replaced

Tags: toilet

[image]

My water-saving toilet was given by local utility company to save water many years ago.  This is in Southern California. The bowl has a dish inside. A handle on the left side is pressed down and the dish is flipped to allow water to go down.  The dish is balanced on both ends and now the end plastic is disintegrated. I use 2 long screws to temporarily hold the dish and manually flip it.

I have looked internet and asked local plumping specialty stores for parts to no avail.  Has anyone seen this model, and know where to order a new dish?

Comment: Parts and shopping assistance is not our format here. Have you searched the unit for markings to ascertain its manufacturer and if possible model number?  Have you searched for an authorized dealer of that manufacturer?   Those are your next steps.   Also one very potent way to fix plastic things is fiberglass + epoxy layup, as is done with FRP boats.  You need to lightly sand the plastic to give it a crunchy surface for the epoxy to adhere to.

Comment: Go back to your local utility that supplied the system. They will have a vested interest in pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: remove the dish and put a milk jug filled with water into the tank

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. They gave me the idea to look hard for the manufacturer and model name.  I found it underneath the toilet seat.  I searched Amazon and found/ordered the repair kit: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=niagara+flapperless+toilet+parts&crid=1XE5AGJEM83OO&sprefix=niagara++flap%2Caps%2C240&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_1_12.   I think this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy remedy, remove it and replace it with bricks or something not water soluble that does not float. That will take up the space and reduce the volume of the tank. That solution works quite well in most toilet tanks.